# JQuery CSS pseudo class selector works in console but not from script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Not sure what I'm missing here but I'm trying to change the graphics on an anchor tag.  It works from the console but not from the script.  The arrow to the right of the text should switch between up and down.

JS:

```
//initialize prodToggle and then:

prodToggle = -prodToggle;
if(prodToggle) {
  $('#prod').addClass('upClass').removeClass('downClass');
} else {
     $('#prod').addClass('downClass').removeClass('upClass');
}
```

CSS:

```
#mytable a.upClass::after {
  content: '\2227';
}

#mytable a.downClass::after {
  content: '\2228';
}
```

HTML:

```
<table id="mytable">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="#" id="myAnchor" class="upClass" onClick="flipflop();">Test</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[Here's a pseudo-code Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/raydot/z1yef940/)

Comment: Just FYI a non-working "pseudo-code" jsfiddle is not useful.

Comment: Also, what's important here is the value of "prodToggle". Both positive and negative non-zero numeric values test as `true`. The variable "prodToggle" should be initialized to either `true` or `false`, and then its value can be toggled with the `!` operator.

Comment: First, it's always advisable to make sure jQuery is loaded before trying to call it. Wrap any jQuery code in a self-calling function with jQuery as a parameter. Second, you should try putting an alert or console.log in your JavaScript just to make sure it's getting called. Failing to do this before asking a question has caused many a red face.

Comment: Adam, understandable but I didn't really want to get wrapped up in fiddling with the Fiddle.  Pointy given that I gave enough of an example to get my question answered I'd say it was entirely useful, but thanks for being that one guy in every thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your jsfiddle was completely messed up: you had a missing id on your table, the selector you were giving JQuery selected nothing, and the `flipflop` function was undefined.

Once it's cleaned up a bit, it works properly.

```js
flipflop = function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('#myAnchor').toggleClass('upClass downClass');
}
```

```css
#mytable a.upClass::after {
  content: '\2227';
}
#mytable a.downClass::after {
  content: '\2228';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mytable">
  <tr>
    <td> <a href="#" id="myAnchor" class="upClass" onclick="flipflop(event);">Test</a>

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Ah...my problem was that I should have split this off into its own event handler instead of trying to run it as a simple conditional.  No wonder it worked in the console and not in the code.  Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

I guess your `prodToggle` is the problem. You should use `true` and    `false` as the possible values and I dont think `-true=false` .  but:     `!true=false`